# How to change the url query-params for the tested polymer component with sinon

Tags: javascript, polymer, sinon

I have the component built with Polymer 2, and i have some behavior what calling function when query-params flag exist in url. But how i can test it with Sinon?

Component checking query-params with:

```
new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

and if

```
this.switcher = urlParams.get('some-flag')
```

i need to call function. I did this behavior in connectedCallback.

It possible to change url with sinon to test this behavior?

I tried to make fake checking url function and set this.switcher flag manually with recalling connectedCallback but it not help me at all.

I can't find in documentation any advice about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can [stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) the `get` method of [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to return what you want:

```
sinon.stub(URLSearchParams.prototype, 'get').returns('some-value');
```

If you need more complex logic to mock the return value of the `get` method, you can use the `callsFake` method of sinon stubs.

Comment: For component it will give affect? URLSearchParams inside connectedCallback, not sure it will work

Comment: As long as you stub the `get` method before your component executes that line of code, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I altered the answer from @mgarcia a bit, and this worked for me:

```
urlSearchParams = sinon.stub(URLSearchParams.prototype, "get"); 
urlSearchParams.returns('some new data');
function_under_test();
assert.equal( place_assert_stuff_here );
urlSearchParams.restore();
```